# Cannot find the ToolStripDropDownButton in design toolbox

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I am making a form and would like to use a `ToolStripDropDownButton` (basically a button with an arrow pointing down from where u can select an item):

[as found in the Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) but I cannot seem to find it in the form[design] toolbox.

I am using VS2015 C# community version, net framework 4.6. I have tried adding the namespace `using System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton;` but it does not recognize toolstripdropdownbutton. Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton` is a class, is not a namespace.

Comment: I see, thanks. My mistake. Any idea how I can use that class to create the toolstripdropdownbutton control? So far, I have only used controls that I can drag and drop from the design toolbox. Maybe pointing me out on the right direction?

I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5cbt5y9(v=vs.110).aspx 

where they show how initialize this control, but do not where they do it. I have tried it but nothing happens in my form.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. Let me know if you have any question about the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is because `System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton` is a class, is not a namespace.

> Any idea how I can use that class to create the
>   toolstripdropdownbutton control?

**Using Code:**

```
var item = new ToolStripDropDownButton("SomeText");
item.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("SubMenu1"));
item.DropDownItems.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("SubMenu1"));
this.toolStrip1.Items.Add(item);
```

You can also take a look at below constructor to add an image and an event handler and see more example at bottom of documentation page:

- [`ToolStripDropDownButton Constructor (String, Image, EventHandler)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160884(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Result:**

[image]

**Using the designer:**

You can put a `ToolStrip` on form, then click the dropdown of add item. then select `DropDownButton`.

[image]

**More information:**

- [How to: Add ToolStrip Items Dynamically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229625(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ToolStrip Control Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e58c44b8(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I needed. Your screenshots made me realize that when I was trying to use toolstrip earlier I was not able to see the controls on the upper left because a panel was sitting on top of it... Your explanation was very clear and answered my question. I appreciate the effort you put into it, I have marked it as the answer. Thanks again!